# Golang Gorm scope broken after upgrade from v1 to v2

Tags: mysql, go, orm, go-gorm

I was using Gorm v1. I had this scope for pagination which was working correctly:

```
func Paginate(entity BaseEntity, p *Pagination) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        var totalRows int64

        db.Model(entity).Count(&totalRows)
        
        totalPages := int(math.Ceil(float64(totalRows) / float64(p.PerPage)))
        p.TotalPages = totalPages
        p.TotalCount = int(totalRows)
        p.SetLinks(entity.ResourceName())

        return db.Offset(p.Offset).Limit(p.PerPage)
    }
}
```

and the way I called it:

```
if err := gs.db.Scopes(entities.Paginate(genre, p)).Find(&gs.Genres).Error; err != nil {
        return errors.New(err.Error())
    }
```

again, this used to work correctly, that is until I upgraded to Gorm v2. Now I'm getting the following message:

> [0.204ms] [rows:2] SELECT * FROM `genres` LIMIT 2
> sql: expected 9 destination arguments in Scan, not 1; sql: expected 9 destination arguments in Scan, not 1[GIN] 2022/06/18 - 00:41:00 | 400 |      1.5205ms |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/api/v1/genres"
> Error #01: sql: expected 9 destination arguments in Scan, not 1; sql: expected 9 destination arguments in Scan, not 1

Now, I found out that the error is due to this line:
`db.Model(entity).Count(&totalRows)`
because if I remove it then my query is being correctly executed (obviously the data for `TotalPages` is not correct since it wasn't calculated). Going through the documentation I saw https://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html#Multiple-Immediate-Methods so my guess is that the connection used to get `totalRows` is being reused and have some residual data therefore my offset and limit query is failing.
I tried to create a new session for both the count and the offset queries:
`db.Model(entity).Count(&totalRows).Session(&gorm.Session{})`

`return db.Offset(p.Offset).Limit(p.PerPage).Session(&gorm.Session{})`

hoping that each one will use their own session but doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs it:

I did have to create a new session but I wasn't creating it the right way. I ended up doing:

```
countDBSession := db.Session(&gorm.Session{Initialized: true})
countDBSession.Model(entity).Count(&totalRows)
```

and that worked as expecting. So my scope now is:

```
// Paginate is a Gorm scope function.
func Paginate(entity BaseEntity, p *Pagination) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {

        var totalRows int64

        // we must create a new session to run the count, otherwise by using the same db connection
        // we'll get some residual data which will cause db.Offset(p.Offset).Limit(p.PerPage) to fail.
        countDBSession := db.Session(&gorm.Session{Initialized: true})
        countDBSession.Model(entity).Count(&totalRows)

        totalPages := int(math.Ceil(float64(totalRows) / float64(p.PerPage)))
        p.TotalPages = totalPages
        p.TotalCount = int(totalRows)
        p.SetLinks(entity.ResourceName())

        return db.Offset(p.Offset).Limit(p.PerPage)
    }
}
```

notice that I'm using a new session to get the count via `countDBSession` which won't affect the latter use of the `*db.Gorm` parameter in `return db.Offset(p.Offset).Limit(p.PerPage).Session(&gorm.Session{})`

Comment: This is an amazing find and should be in the GORM docs!